# Add Google Analytics to Vaadin (Google analytics Tracker)

Tags: google-analytics, vaadin, vaadin14

Hi i'm new to vaadin and i have a problem implementing google analytics with vaadin.
I have searched a lot in forums and I have not been able to find the solution.
I would like someone with experience in this process to guide me to connect vaadin with google analytics.
I have already created a Google Analytics account and it has generated a JS for me:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-Y3YPVNQBCZ"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-Y3YPVNQBCZ');
</script>
```

My problem now is that in the google analytics Tracker plugin (https://vaadin.com/directory/component/googleanalyticstracker/samples) it does not specify how to add the JS code and I don't know what else to look for, please help !!
I need a little guide because I don't know where to start working
(SOLVED)

Comment: I have already solved it: my problem was that when creating the google analytics property, it did not assign the universal property option and the tracking ID format was not correct, therefore it did not read the navigation data.
By adding @EnableGoogleAnalytics(value = "Tracking ID") and the dependencies and repositories in the pom.xml to the main application it works for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a component you can use:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/googleanalyticstracker/samples

You can use an annotation

https://github.com/samie/vaadin-ga-tracker/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/googleanalytics/tracking/demo/MainLayout.java

Like:

```
@EnableGoogleAnalytics(value = "G-Y3YPVNQBCZ")
```

Comment: You mean that only this part of the code would link my app with GA?

Comment: that code doesn't match my MEASUREMENT ID, where did you get it from?

Comment: This is an example. You have to set your Google Analytics ID

Comment: I mean the format of the id code

Comment: I don't understand your question but I updated my answer

Comment: I think my problem comes from the fact that my application is hosted on a local server and when I configure the data flow in Google Analytics it is not allowing me to obtain the measurements, so I will try to upload it to an online server.